# Can I mock a return value of an asynctask's "doInBackground" method during junit test?

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso

I know this question is weird. But I still want to know is there a way to mock the asynctask's "doInBackgound" methods return value during testing by using Junit and Mokito?

What I want is: the test case will run to execute the asyncTask. During the asyncTask, I want to change the result that will be passed into onPostExecute(). So is there any way to specify the value of the result of doInBackground()?

The reason I want to do this is because:
When Espresso click the button on UI, it will execute the asyncTask which call for a scanner. But during the test I do not really want a scan, so I use mokito to mock a Scanner class and pass it into asyncTask. Since Scanner class is a third party class and I cannot get/set value of it. But I want to specify the scanning result, so I am trying to specify it inside asynctask.

Here is code logic:
This is the app code:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(ScanDataCollection... params) {
        String result = ScanDataCollection.getScanData().getData();
        return result;           
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        /* Do something with "result"*/
    }
```

This is the test code:

```
        ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection = mock(ScanDataCollection.class);
        asyncTask.execute(scanDataCollection);
```

Now what I want is, when asyncTask runs its doInBackground, return a String with value "123";

This asynctask will trigger by user user click the button and use scanner to scan a qr code. But in the test I do not really want to user to "scan". I want to mock the user scan behavior. So i use mokito to mock "ScanDataCollection" object. since "ScanDataCollection" is a third party lib, and it does not have method to set value, then how can I set value to the scan result and make the test case go ahead? So I am trying to figure out I can touch with doingBackground() method in the test and set a return value for it?

Can I do something like when getScanData().getData() is called, return "123"? and How?

Comment: This seems pretty simple, can you provide the code you have already? Mostly the way the `Scanner` works with the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Hi Bartek, I have just add code to it. The code is very simple. I mock the ScanDataCollection in my test file and send it as param to this asyncTask. But this is a third party lib and does not allow me to set value to ScanDataCollection. Then how can I give it a value and make the "result" in doInBackground as the value I want? Then I can make the test case go ahead.